# React native suddenly slow remote data loading

Tags: react-native

I have a react native app the was working fine and now suddenly without changing anything , it started loading plain json files very slow. also loading images is taking 10-15 seconds for a 100 kb image. i googled but nothing helping

any idea?

Comment: Are you talking about iOS or Android and emulator or real device? Have you tried to track network traffic e.g. with Reactotron or similar tool? Do you have any code you could share where you assume the error could be?

Comment: iOS... the same issue is on both emulator and real device. The issue is that every remote call just takes 10-15 seconds. even normal fetching plain json file takes same time

Comment: Reactotron showing 10-15 seconds duration . although loading the same plain JSON Duration via browser is just 1 second

Comment: I don't have any experience with IOS. But did you try to remove the build folder under the android/app path, for android?

Comment: Random, but are you using Redux, and do you have logging enabled? Depending on how your actions/reducers are configured, if they're involved with the fetch at all, logging can seriously impact performance.

Comment: Are you running a debug or a release version of the app? Debug versions are often much slower due to logging etc.

Comment: yes using redux . no logging , and the problem is in release version too

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it may be the problem with your network, you can try connecting your devices through some other hotspot. Furthermore, you can try 'Hot Reloading' feature, it is extremely fast. Hope, this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced this type of problem Just clear cache and restart app and emulator. I will work again faster.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced this before with the app in debug mode. Try building your app in Release configuration and trying it then. If it's just an issue in debug mode, then its simply an inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, this issue arises because of running the app in Debug mode.

#### Things to take care of:

- If you are running on a slow network connection.
- If you are using stale/old cache again and again.
- If you are loading the latest version of your code.

#### Some of the ways you can approach this problem:

- Delete stale/old cache from your running configuration.
- Switch to a network with nice connectivity.
- Try to use **Hot Module Reloading** (HMR) or the hot reloading feature created for the react ecosystem.

I hope this might help and solves your problem. Cheers!